# How do I interrupt() a thread given its ThreadInfo object?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a situation in which I need to do some thread cleanup while the application is running. (This in turn is largely due to library design choices, which unfortunately are outside of my control.)

I do not have access to any relevant [java.lang.Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) instance, because the thread is created outside of my code's control. This means that the simple approaches suggested at for example [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html), [How to Stop a Thread](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html) and [How can I interrupt a thread created from within a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32085528/486504) don't really help me, because they all rely on the Thread instance either being available, or being possible to make available.

I **do** however have (brand new) code that calls [ThreadMXBean.dumpAllThreads()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#dumpAllThreads-boolean-boolean-), which returns [ThreadInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html)[]. This looked like a good starting point for cleaning up, since the returned array gives me all the information I need to determine which specific threads, if any, need to be cleaned up.

From what I understand, what I want to do is to call [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--). See for example [How exactly do I interrupt a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31074284/486504). The problem with this is that I can't seem to find any way to do so given only a ThreadInfo object.

With the above said, I am ready to state the question:

**How do I get from a ThreadInfo object to a corresponding Thread object, so that I can call methods on the Thread object instance?**

*Alternatively,* **what is some other method of effectively calling Thread.interrupt() on a thread given only a ThreadInfo object describing the thread?**

Suggested solutions should ideally work with both Java 7 and Java 8. They need to work with Java 8.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ThreadInfo you have the thread id so you can use it to obtain a reference to a thread.

Read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667496/get-reference-to-thread-object-from-its-id) about how to do it.

I'd do something like this:

```
ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = ....;
Set<Long> tIds = new HashSet<>();
for (ThreadInfo tIndo : threadInfos) {
  tIds.add(tIndo.getId());
}
for (Thread t : Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()) {
  if(tIds.contains(t.getId()) {
    t.interrupt();
  }
}
```

Comment: this should be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: Added some code. In my opinion this was an answer even without an example.

Comment: Compare [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/157730)

Comment: I ended up using the result from `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()`, which is already a `Set<Thread>`, rather than going through the `ThreadInfo` array, but this pointed me in the right direction and with the code IMO it is an answer to the question as asked. Thank you!